# Using a variable for a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro and am having issues with using a range variable. I think I am setting the range properly, but I cannot do anything with the range. Pseudocode below:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Report(1)      'A function which will be defined below

trackWkbk.Sheets(strFY).rng = 10       <--'THIS IS WHERE I am getting the error. 

'trackWbkb is a workbook that is defined properly; I use it elsewhere with no errors.
'strFY is defined and working properly, I use it to call sheets in trackWbkb elsewhere with no errors.
```

The sub function code is:

```
Function Report(a) As Range
    Select Case intMonth
        Case intMonth = 7
        Select Case a
            Case a = 1
                Set Report = Range("B2")
        End Select
    End Select
End Function
```

I know my select case statements are gonna get pretty convoluted (this is just a testing sample), but I don't think the issue is there.

Let me know if I should include more code. My code compiles. I think this is something simple that I am missing, but I have been looking online for the past half hour and can't seem to find anything that will resolve this. Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: A quick fix would be: `trackWkbk.Sheets(strFY).Range(rng.Address) = 10`

Comment: Hey, I tried this, but unfortunately it still is giving me the same error. I even tried to add a .Value to the end, but no such luck. Still, I appreciate your response!

Answer (score 0):

Your function already returns a `Range` object. It's not clear to me whether you're trying to obtain a range on another worksheet that is at the same address as a range on the active worksheet. However, you could directly obtain the desired range if you passed the worksheet reference to your function:

```
Function Report(ByVal poParentWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal a As Integer) As Range
    Select Case intMonth
        Case intMonth = 7
        Select Case a
            Case a = 1
                Set Report = poParentWorksheet.Range("B2")
        End Select
    End Select
End Function
```

Then you could use:

```
Set rng = Report(trackWkbk.Sheets(strFY), 1)
rng.Value = 10
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your response. I am a  little confused by what you mean. Does I put that in the place I am getting the error? Don't I have to set what rng is?

Answer (score 0):

When you set a range variable you are creating a pointer in memory to a specific range in a specific sheet. It's not storing a cell address, so you can't write

```
 trackWkbk.Sheets(strFY).rng
```

Either adopt Excelosaurus's solution, or change your function to return a cell address as a string and then use

```
 trackWkbk.Sheets(strFY).range(rng)
```